# Does anybody have a plaintext file of every single crime? like just the names of every crime compiled?

Tags: list

Dont need it to be computer parseable

I dont care if there are false positives either.

and when I say every crime I mean EVERY crime. like the name of every type of crime. even names like white hat wiretapping will work fine

Comment: Worldwide?  Every country has different laws, and in the US there are 50 sets of state laws + federal laws.  There are also religious and cultural laws.  Also, welcome to SO and please read tour - https://stackoverflow.com/tour and what not to ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Also, "white hat wiretapping" probably isn't going to be an actual, legal name for the crime in any set of laws.